# Excel error message "An invalid value was used while saving to WK1 format"

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a cell that evaluates just fine, but it comes with the warning that "An invalid value was used while saving to WK1 format". When I google this, I get basically no results. I find this very mysterious, does anyone know what it means?

I am using Microsoft Excel 2010.

I have found out that WK1 is a Lotus 1-2-3 format, which I have never used.

The formula in the cell is

```
="Some text" & IF(I56|"  (Top 5)"|"")
```

The cell `I56` contains the formula

```
=L56>0
```

and `L56` a formula of the type

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(...|Match(...|...|0))|0)
```

Comment: @Excellll: I hit this error as well, without any | - just a straight up Cell*Cell*(1+Cell)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this would be considered an answer or not, but given the complete lack of any information on the subject, and given that this is the second result when you google the problem, I figured I'd add a few more details. Simply clicking around a few times and selecting the cells in question made the error message go away.

Best I can guess is that there was a minor corruption when auto-saving, and Excel went "Hang on, error message happened". Then a bit later, it properly auto-saved, and Excel went "Oh ok, we're happy now, let's remove the error message".

A brief reading over several other posts on the subject seem to have similar "Well nothing changed but the error went away" solution when custom formatting was NOT involved. When formatting is involved, check for a custom format hiding among several "standard" formats, and see if it's being evaluated with them.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to other commenters, I just had this pop up.  I just did a recalculation of the workbook (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F9) and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem and found that one of the cells that was in the sum range was formatted as CUSTOM while all of the other cells were formatted as CURRENCY. The cell had no value in it but was part of a SUM formula so the different formatting caused the error.